# How to set a custom default style in a dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl that holds a TabControl inside. The UserControl is in a seperate project, as a library (dll), so I can reuse it in other projects.
At first I made a custom style for the TabControl, in the Resources property of the UserControl, to better fit the style of the UserControl.

While I'm happy with the result, I want to be able to customize the style from outside. So I setup a dependancy property for the Style of the TabControl.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabCtr" 
                SelectedIndex="{Binding selectedIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                Style="{Binding StyleTabControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource HeaderDataTemplateSelector}" 
                ContentTemplate="{Binding TabContentTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
```

The question is, how can I default to the custom style in the UserControls resources, if no style is bound from the outside (Application using the UserControl)?

I tried saving the Style on a local static variable,

```
private static Style defaultFixiatedTabControlStyle;
```

initialising it in the UserControls constructor

```
public DynamicTabControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tabCtr.DataContext = this;
            defaultFixiatedTabControlStyle = this.FindResource("FixatedTabControl") as Style;
        }
```

and setting the default of the dependancy property to the the variable:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StyleTabControlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                                       "StyleTabControl", 
                                        typeof(Style), 
                                        typeof(DynamicTabControl), 
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                                            defaultFixiatedTabControlStyle , 
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStyleChanged)));
```

But that did not work :(

Thank you in advance for helping me out here.

Comment: Instead of specifying a default value by property metadata, try `SetCurrentValue(StyleTabControlProperty, this.FindResource("FixatedTabControl") as Style);` in the constructor.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I have been banging my head on the table over this for the entire day. You rock!